# Why cassandra slower to import schema

Tags: database, import, cassandra, schema

I exported a schema of my cassandra. Look the case, my environment have 40.000 tables in keyspace (product).

After 4 days importing this schema in a new cluster, I have just 10.000 tables imported. It´s normal? How Can I import this schema faster? Any suggestion?

Regards,

Comment: Side note: 40,000! I'm amazed that even runs. Thats the highest I've ever even heard of, usually things break down long before then. How do you run repairs?

Comment: Yeah, I'd say that's normal.  Having 10k-40k tables in a cluster is what's *not* normal.

Answer (score 1):

First off: seriously consider changing your data model. 40k tables is far beyond what Cassandra is designed to handle. Usually people get told to consider changing things at around 1000. Each table has a serious amount of overhead that must remain in memory and there are operations that fire off per-table tasks.

While you should test it something that could work as a hack is to turn a fresh new cluster *completely off* after starting it. Every node down. Then copy the system_schema tables from any one of your current nodes to all the new clusters nodes. You might need to create the folder structure as well for the keyspaces and tables. Then bring new cluster up. Test it out before trying it though but I believe that will work with 3.x.